# Как обвернуть в класс обработчик и функцию декоратор

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, декоратор

Как обвернуть в класс ниже приведенный код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Tele = Telegram()
    #Tele.run()
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start_command(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello!")
    bot.polling()
```

В итоге должно получиться нечто подобное:

```
import telebot

class Telegram():
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = '...'
        self.bot = telebot.TeleBot('...')
    
        @self.bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
        def start_command(self, message):
            self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello!")
    
    def run(self):
        self.bot.polling()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tele = Telegram()
    Tele.run()
```

Comment: `@self.bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])` и `self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello!")`?

Comment: если приходит сообщение, что пришла команда старт, то отправляется в ответ хелоу

Comment: селфы добавил, не работает все равно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import telebot


class Telegram:
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = '...'
        self.bot = telebot.TeleBot(self.token)

        @self.bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
        def start_command(message):
            self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello!")

    def run(self):
        self.bot.polling()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tele = Telegram()
    Tele.run()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Нужно было из функции  start_command убрать первый аргумент

Comment: @helldrg, пожалуйста :)